# Trying to reinstall the snap store

Tags: snap, snap-store

I tried uninstalling the snap system but it seems there's some things I wasn't aware of or understood. I tried reinstalling:

```
sudo snap install snap-store

2023-10-18T12:03:29-04:00 INFO Waiting for automatic snapd restart... error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "gtk-common-themes" (1535) (cannot proceed, expected snap "gtk-common-themes" revision 1535 to be mounted but is not)
- Mount snap "gnome-42-2204" (141) (cannot proceed, expected snap "gnome-42-2204" revision 141 to be mounted but is not)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'd rather get everything functioning again before I decide to uninstall/remove at a later date.

Thanks.

Ubuntu 23.10.1

Comment: First, remove snap altogether, with `sudo apt purge --autoremove snapd`. Then, install snapd, and manually install all the snaps you need.

Comment: And this will remove everything including these mount points?

Comment: Yes, it should. Let us know how it goes

Comment: I ran the suggested command and received this:

https://pastebin.com/jh1dmTLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First run
`sudo systemctl stop var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount`, followed by
`sudo systemctl disable var-snap-firefox-common-host\\x2dhunspell.mount`

Then run
`sudo apt purge --autoremove snapd` to remove snap.

Afterwards,install snapd with

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

Then, install snap store with

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

You will also have to manually install Firefox and other snaps.

Comment: Awesome. It worked. Thanks for all your help, Archisman.

Comment: @vaskark You can accept my answer by clicking on the checkmark on the left side, if it answers your question